# Line separators in AvalonEdit

Tags: avalonedit

I'm using the AvalonEdit control to show data where each line is its own entity, and the lines often wrap.  Wrapping allows me to show all the data on the screen at a time, but it can be confusing for users to differentiate between lines and wrapped lines.
Does anyone know if any of the following are possible (ordered by my preference)?

1. Give the lines a larger seperator size than wrapped lines.
2. Color the separator space between lines, but not between wrapped lines.
3. Alternate background colors per line.

Thanks for your help.